# Schengen travel with Swiss residence attestation?

Tags: schengen, switzerland, attestation

I'm confused about the rights of non-EU *residents* living in Switzerland. Due to the pandemic Swiss residence permits are taking much long to process than they ever would have in the past. In lieu of issuing a residence permit a residence attestation may be attained.

Can entry of Schengen area be permitted with a residence attestation for a non-EU national?

Answer (score 3):

No, you will not even be allowed to enter (at least not straightforwardly) Switzerland with a residence attestation.

If your long-stay D visa is still valid, you may enter Switzerland or other Schengen countries with that (assuming multi-entry).

Otherwise you need to ask for a return visa (visa de retour / Rückreisevisa) from your cantonal authority.